# Julia: how to get a random permutation of a given string s?

Tags: string, julia, permutation

I thought about two different ways, but both seem pretty ugly.

1. Transform the string `s` into an array `a` by `split`ting it, then use `sample(a, length(s), replace=false)` and `join` the array again into a string
2. Get a `RandomPermutation` `r` of length `length(s)` and `join` the single `s[i]` for `i` in `r`.

What's the right way? Unfortunately there is no method matching `sample(::String, ::Int64; replace=false)`.

Comment: `join(collect(s)[randperm(length(s))])`

Comment: at least second way has problem with unicode. `function sample(s::String)  join(getindex([i for i in s], randperm(length(s)))) end;sample("ďaľšý")` seems to work with unicode too. (but Dan's solution is nicer! :)

Comment: If you know for a fact that it's an ASCII string: `s[randperm(end)]`. Otherwise: `join(shuffle!(collect(s)))`.  And perhaps a nice way to write that: `s |> collect |> shuffle! |> join`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps defining a `shuffle` method for `String` constitutes type piracy, but, anyway, here's a suggested implemetation:

```
Base.shuffle(s::String) = isascii(s) ? s[randperm(end)] : join(shuffle!(collect(s)))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to squeeze out performance from `shuffle` then you can consider:

```
function shufflefast(s::String)
    ss = sizeof(s)
    l = length(s)

    ss == l && return String(shuffle!(copy(Vector{UInt8}(s))))

    v = Vector{Int}(l)
    i = start(s)
    for j in 1:l
        v[j] = i
        i = nextind(s, i)
    end

    p = pointer(s)
    u = Vector{UInt8}(ss)
    k = 1
    for i in randperm(l)
        for j in v[i]:(i == l ? ss : v[i+1]-1)
            u[k] = unsafe_load(p, j)
            k += 1
        end
    end
    String(u)
end
```

For large strings it is over 4x faster for ASCII and 3x faster for UTF-8.

Unfortunately it is messy - so I would rather treat it as an exercise. However, it uses only exported functions so it is not a hack.

Comment: Faster than what? If excercise then you probably don't need to run whole length: `all(((codeunit(s,i) & 0xc0) == 0x80) for i in 1:sizeof(s))` instead of `sizeof(s) == length(s)`. Although I am not sure about generator here - they seems to be slow in Julia.

Comment: I use `sizeof(s) == length(s)` because they are later used in UTF-8 part. If I used `ascii(s)` I would have to calculate them again later so this way I avoid running `ascii(s)`. But I agree that it decreases the performance of ASCII part a bit (not much as for ASCII string you have to go to its end anyway).

Comment: and the speed comparison is to the implementation `Base.shuffle(s::String)` proposed in the first answer.

Comment: we could probably allocate `v = Vector{Int}(ss)` and check if `nextind` return bigger index than ss to gain some speed...

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the optimization tricks in Bogumil Kaminski's answer, the following is a version with almost the same performance, but a bit clearer (in my opinion) and using a second utility function which may be of value in itself:

```
function strranges(s)      # returns the ranges of bytes spanned by chars
    u = Vector{UnitRange{Int64}}()
    sizehint!(u,sizeof(s))
    i = 1
    while i<=sizeof(s)
        ii = nextind(s,i)
        push!(u,i:ii-1)
        i = ii
    end
    return u
end

function shufflefast(s)
    ss = convert(Vector{UInt8},s)
    uu = Vector{UInt8}(length(ss))
    i = 1
    @inbounds for r in shuffle!(strranges(s))
        for j in r
            uu[i] = ss[j]
            i += 1
        end
    end
    return String(uu)
end
```

Example timing:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> s = "ďaľšý"

julia> @btime shuffle($s)       # shuffle from DNF's answer
  831.200 ns (9 allocations: 416 bytes)
"ýľďša"

julia> @btime shufflefast($s)   # shuffle from this answer
  252.224 ns (5 allocations: 432 bytes)
"ľýďaš"

julia> @btime kaminskishufflefast($s)  # shuffle from Kaminski's answer
  197.345 ns (4 allocations: 384 bytes)
"ýašďľ"
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: a little better performance - see code comments

This is from Bogumil Kaminski's answer where I am trying to avoid calculating length (*) if it is not necessary:

```
function shufflefast2(s::String)
    ss = sizeof(s)
    local l

    for l in 1:ss
        #if ((codeunit(s,l) & 0xc0) == 0x80)
        if codeunit(s,l)>= 0x80  # edit (see comments bellow why)
            break
        end
    end

    ss == l && return String(shuffle!(copy(Vector{UInt8}(s))))

    v = Vector{Int}(ss)
    i = 1
    l = 0
    while i<ss
        l += 1
        v[l] = i
        i = nextind(s, i)
    end
    v[l+1] = ss+1  # edit - we could do this because ss>l

    p = pointer(s)
    u = Vector{UInt8}(ss)
    k = 1
    for i in randperm(l)
        # for j in v[i]:(i == l ? ss : v[i+1]-1)
        for j in v[i]:v[i+1]-1  # edit we could do this because v[l+1] is defined (see above)
            u[k] = unsafe_load(p, j)
            k += 1
        end
    end
    String(u)
end
```

Example timing for ascii string:

```
julia> srand(1234);@btime for i in 1:100 danshufflefast("test") end
  19.783 μs (500 allocations: 34.38 KiB)

julia> srand(1234);@btime for i in 1:100 bkshufflefast("test") end
  10.408 μs (300 allocations: 18.75 KiB)

julia> srand(1234);@btime for i in 1:100 shufflefast2("test") end
  10.280 μs (300 allocations: 18.75 KiB)
```

Difference is too small, sometimes bkshufflefast is faster. Performance has to be equal. Whole length has to be count and there is same allocation.

Example timing for unicode string:

```
julia> srand(1234);@btime for i in 1:100 danshufflefast(s) end
  24.964 μs (500 allocations: 42.19 KiB)

julia> srand(1234);@btime for i in 1:100 bkshufflefast(s) end
  20.882 μs (400 allocations: 37.50 KiB)

julia> srand(1234);@btime for i in 1:100 shufflefast2(s) end
  19.038 μs (400 allocations: 40.63 KiB)
```

shufflefast2 is a little but clearly faster here. A little more allocation than Bogumil's function and a little less allocation than in Dan's solution.

(*) - I a little hope that String implementation in Julia will be faster in future and length could be much quicker than it is now.

Comment: A takeaway from this question (and answer) could be a better `isascii` defined as: `fastisascii(s) = ( for l in 1:sizeof(s) codeunit(s,l) & 0xc0 == 0x80 && return false ; end ; true )` . You think it should be made into PR ? Perhaps the Julia codegen should be improved so current `isascii` generates similar code.

Comment: @DanGetz it could be nice! :) `isascii(s::String) = ( for l in 1:sizeof(s) codeunit(s,l) >= 0x80 && return false ; end ; true )` could work too (and faster). It probably has to be specialized because there could be different string implementations. String concrete type is using UTF-8 encoding so this method has to be fine (we need some more tests probably?). About pull request - your contribution is bigger than mine and I am pretty new to github. So I'll be glad you make this PR! :)

Comment: My "isascii" in fastshuffle2 was inspired by `@edit Base.is_valid_continuation(codeunit("-", 1))` but it could be simplified according to `@edit isascii("")` (you inspired me to look at :) ...